Show "Add New" button only for current CPT
I made a custom CPT "Blog" and disabled the standard "Posts" CPT. However, when I'm on a Blog single or archive page, the "Add New" button lets me create a Post, not a Blog which is problematic because my client will create a post and then not be able to find it. When I hover over it gives me all the options of post types to add a post in.
What I'm used to is that once I'm on a Blog page, it only shows a button to add a new Blog post. How can I change this?
The button and the options I get
I have tried to Google for solutions, but I'm finding issues that are different from mine.
